# pyqt 5.7, cannot open linker script file QtCore.exp

Tags: compiler-errors, pyqt5, yocto, openembedded

I am trying to compile pyqt 5.7 in the yocto build environment, but I am getting the following error.

```
/usr/libexec/i586-poky-linux/gcc/i586-poky-linux/6.2.0/ld: cannot open linker script file QtCore.exp: No such file or directory
```

Here are the complete configure/compile outputs.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/89cd9131378577f2383d61117389c708

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?

Comment: I wound up modifying the configure script to remove the reference to the .exp file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're specifying a version script when calling gcc:

```
--version-script=QtCore.exp
```

You are probably missing this file (QtCore.exp) and ld is complaining about it.

From `man ld`:

> --version-script=version-scriptfile
>
> Specify the name of a version script to the linker.  This is typically
>   used when creating shared libraries to specify additional information
>   about the version hierarchy for the library being created.  This
>   option is only fully supported on ELF platforms which support shared
>   libraries; see VERSION.  It is partially supported on PE platforms,
>   which can use version scripts to filter symbol visibility in
>   auto-export mode: any symbols marked local in the version script will
>   not be exported.

In this case, the version-script option is adding shared library versioning support to Qt. For more interesting things that this option can do, Ulrich Drepper wrote a great paper called ["How To Write Shared Libraries"](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf). If you read and understand this paper you'll know more than most people about shared libraries and managing ABI stability.

You can try removing this option, but better yet would be to find where the file (QtCore.exp) lives, who generates it, and updating the path to match.

Comment: That option is auto-generated by the *configure.py* script when it generates the makefile for the QtCore module. It gets added to the *QtCore/QtCore.pro* file in the `QMAKE_LFLAGS`.

Comment: @ekhumoro I would assume that the version script content is also created and a file saved somewhere. It would be silly to generate a configuration that requires a missing script, right?  :)

Comment: Well, I've heard that it's possible for software to have bugs - so who knows? Anyway, I was only trying to provide the information you referred to in the last sentence of your answer.

Comment: I modified the ```configure.py``` to not add the reference in ```QMAKE_LFLAGS```. It fixed the build. There shouldn't be any issue doing this, right?

Comment: @PaulKnopf. Not sure. I think the problem is that `QMAKE_LFLAGS` gets a relative path to the `.exp` file - so maybe you could fix `configure.py` so that it sets an absolute path. Something like: `pro_lines.append('QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--version-script=%s.exp' % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(mname, target_name)))`.

Comment: @PaulKnopf I agree with ekhumoro. Only remove it if you know for sure that version script isn't needed. If you are unsure, try to fix the path so that ld can find the file.